# ajax contact form error with select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've ajax contact from with input field and select element and it does not gives results as it should be.

HTML Form Code (name as input and iphone as select element)

```
 <div id="contact_form">
    <form name="contact" method="post" action="">Name
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />Iphone
        <select name="iphone" id="iphone">
            <option value="Iphone 4" selected>Iphone 4</option>
            <option value="Iphone 4S">Iphone 4S</option>
            <option value="5">Iphone 5</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send"
        />
    </form>
</div>
```

JS code

```
   $(function () {
       $('.error').hide();
       var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&iphone=' + iphone;
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "send.php",
           data: dataString,
           success: function () {
               $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
               $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
                   .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
                   .hide()
           }
       });
       return false;
   });
```

PHP (send.php) code

```
<?PHP
$name = $_POST['name'];
$iphone = $_POST['iphone'];

$email="my@mail.com";
$from="anyone@mail.com";

$subject="Contact Email";
$headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1256\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $from\r\n";

$mailtext="name : $name - Iphone : $iphone";

mail($email,$subject,$mailtext,$headers);
?>
```

results when i using the from with anyone name

```
Name : anyone - Iphone : [object HTMLSelectElement]
```

[object HTMLSelectElement] ***this is the error***
seems that select element is not working and not passing its value selected

so any idea ? ~ thanks

Comment: How you are getting value of name from this code `var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&iphone=' + iphone;`. You have not defined the variable. You said you are getting value of name properly (Name : anyone - Iphone : [object HTMLSelectElement])

Comment: did any of the answers work for you?

Comment: @user962206 i'm sorry didn't worked either and i still have the same problem but i'll make deep searching cause i've found many are having problem with select element why not send its choice.

Comment: I am having the same error too. that's why I am asking.

Comment: @user962206 this Friday i will spend all my day searching for solution to this problem and if i found one will let you know and you too if found any just drop me comment here with the link :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code a little bit, what I did was attach a submit handler on your form, prevented the default action and here's the important part. I serialize the contents of your form. try this and tell me how this works out. I usually submit my ajaxified forms like this. though I am not sure if it's a good practice but you should try this out.

```
   $(function () {

        $('.error').hide();
        $('form[name=contact]').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();        
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "send.php",
                data: form_data,
                success: function () {
                    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
                        .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
                        .hide()
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're getting the iPhone value like so:

```
var iphone = $("#iphone").val();
```

`$.post` would be more elegant for what you're doing...

```
$.post("send.php", { name: name, iphone: iphone },
   function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });
```